# Add an "ungooglable" tag for questions of the form "Just give me a link"

Tags: feature-request, tags, link-only-answers

Can someone add an "ungooglable" tag for questions where I just want someone to give me a link (rather than a long on-the-fly possibly incorrect answer)

I.e. for questions such as "What does operator X do?" "How do you use the 'in/is/do' keyword" in language L.

These questions generally already have well-thought out professional answers and may be long and complicated, but because the keyword in question is short or common or Google doesn't recognize the token as a query, it can be very hard to find these online.

For these sorts of questions I often go to Stack Overflow in hope someone can point me to the proper documentation or at least give me some keywords to Google. I'm not interested in answers that rehash these things in a briefer less careful manner; I just want a link.

Comment: So you want answers that are only a link? Sounds like the opposite of this site.

Comment: I think you're looking for [tag:go]

Comment: You can use the search box on Stack Exchange sites to search for tokens/operators. Just use `""` around them. (e.g. `[haskell] ">>="`)

Comment: Please no, we have enough issues with link-only answers right now.  You are just asking for this site to become full of answers that could eventually break when the "link" goes down.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that a link is going to lead to better information that an answer here, or, more importantly, what benefit your question gets from this tag.

Comment: [**NO**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5g8yG.png).

Comment: When you want to find the documentation for an operator just search for the list of *all* operators for a language.  In virtually all programming languages in existence the list of all operators is small enough to find the one that you want.  From there you can get it's proper name that you can search on.

Comment: One of the reasons this request is not a good idea is that some of the best online resources about "ungoogleable" operators are answers on StackOverflow (for instance, [this post on * and ** in Python function calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)). If the asker had put an "ungoogleable" tag, perhaps someone would have simply pointed to the (not as clear) official documentation and the internet wouldn't have that resource.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, we are not going to do this.

Here's the harsh truth: we don't care about *your* needs as much as the needs of future readers. Sure, someone in the comments can give you a quick link, but does that help 4 years down the road when someone else has the same problem?

I've been to too many asp.net forum pages where "answers" (if you can even call them that) are just links, and they are broken. I get frustrated by this. If someone is going to go through the trouble of posting an answer, at least POST THE ANSWER.

We want high-quality answers on this site, not a signpost to a better location.

Answer (score 10):

## No.

---

That's not the purpose of Stack Overflow. *At all*. It was designed to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers, not as a site to help individual people with their problems. Link only answers are already a problem and your suggestion will make it even worse.

Here's why I think it's a bad idea:

- **It is pointless** - We already have a lot of confusing tags on the site. This one doesn't serve any practical purpose. If anything, it would confuse new users even more. It'd create unnecessary chaos: people editing in [ungoogleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ungoogleable) tag, arguing whether a particular question should be tagged with it or not etc.
- **Link only answers are not answers** - Stack Exchange even has an [official policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) on this. Link-only answers aren't acceptable anywhere on SE. If you're feeling extra helpful and want to help the OP by directing them to the link, **use comments**. That's exactly what they're for. You can help the OP, future visitors can find the link, and even if the link goes down in future, it's only a comment. Nobody loses anything.
- **It doesn't benefit anyone** - Say we add this tag. What good does it do? It wouldn't help organize anything. The only thing it would do is to create a list of RTFM questions. It's not helpful to the OP, or anyone else reading the question.